# MongoDB / Mongoose schema for users

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I start by saying I'm a beginner with mongodb, but I'm developing a webapp just to study this db in more depth.
I can't "think" of a valid solution (at the schema level), which allows me to manage users and the data associated with them in this case:
I have three types of users: "basic user", "user manager" and "supervisor".
The basic user must be able to see only his data, the “user manager“ must be able to see his data and the data of the users under him. In cascade, the supervisor user must be able to see his data, those of the manager and users under him.

-Practical example:
a user "X" has been assigned tasks, if user "X" has a manager "R", the manager must see his tasks and the tasks of "X". In cascade, if the manager has a supervisor, the supervisor must be able to see his tasks, those of "R" and those of "X."

Any advice or example?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create one collection to store the user details.

Example - `UserSchema`

```
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    managerId: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    superVisorId: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    roleId: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        enum: [EMPLOYEE, MANAGER, SUPERVISOR],
        default: [EMPLOYEE]
    }
```

- Here `userId` is something which you can assign uniquely to each user.
- Now you can write some middleware which checks the roleId when a user is trying to access data of say -> `EMPLOYEE` is trying to access data of `MANAGER` based on the roleId you can reject this action.

You can have another collection `taskSchema`

```
    taskId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    taskDescription: {
        type: String
    },
    // Store the userId from userSchema,
    // This refers to whom this particular task is assigned to.
    taskAssignedTo: {
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        unique: true
    }
```

- Now, If the `SUPERVISOR` want's to access all the tasks that have been assigned to `them` You can simply run a query to first fetch all the `MANAGERS` and then fetch all the `EMPLOYEE` under that manager and store them.
- Now just fetch all the tasks assigned to each of these userIds.